# Sum of column from subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, subquery

The below diagram represents relationships between three tables in an Access database.

- Table `[Shared Mailbox]` contains a list of shared mailboxes (SMB) in Exchange.
- Table `[Shared Mailbox User]` lists the email addresses that have access to a shared mailbox.
- Table `[Exchange Census]` contains the details of all mailboxes whether that of a person or a shared mailbox.  The column `[Exchange Mailbox].MailboxSize(MB)` is the size of a mailbox.

For each `[Shared Mailbox].SharedMailbox`, I need to sum the volume of the user mailboxes that have access to it.

I am working with the below query:

```
SELECT  [Shared Mailbox].SharedMailbox, [Shared Mailbox].MailboxSmtpAddress,
(select Sum([MailboxSize(MB)]) from [Exchange Census] Where ([Shared Mailbox].SharedMailbox = [Shared Mailbox User].SharedMailbox) And 
([Shared Mailbox User].UserEmail = [Exchange Census].PrimarySmtpAddress) Group by [Shared Mailbox].SharedMailbox ) AS UserMailboxVolume
FROM ([Shared Mailbox] 
INNER JOIN [Exchange Census] ON [Shared Mailbox].MailboxSmtpAddress = [Exchange Census].PrimarySmtpAddress) 
INNER JOIN [Shared Mailbox User] ON [Shared Mailbox].SharedMailbox = [Shared Mailbox User].SharedMailbox;
```

This produces a result set that looks like this, where the subquery returns the size of the child mailboxes rather than their sum:

[image]

What do I need to change to get one row per SMB with the aggregate volume of the mailboxes for those who have access?

[image]

Comment: Should edit question to show sample raw data and desired output.

Comment: Let me clarify.   For SharedMailbox 208CST the correct result would be a single row where UserMailbox is the sum of the numbers shown in the above screen shot.

Comment: Peh:   I applied your code edit, however it does not produce the desired result.   I still get multiple (detail) rows for each mailbox instead of a single, row for their sum.

Comment: Still looking for sample raw data. I know you want one row per SharedMailbox, but I need data to test. I am somewhat confused by relationships. So show tables with some representative data and result that should come from the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your data structures or requirements, I believe you should join the `Exchange Census` table to your `Shared Mailbox User` table (since it is the **user's** mailbox whose size you are looking to calculate), and omit the correlated subquery entirely.

I would suggest something along the lines of the following:

```sql
select
    sm.sharedmailbox,
    sm.mailboxsmtpaddress,
    sum(ec.[MailboxSize(MB)]) as usermailboxvolume
from
    (
        [shared mailbox] sm inner join [shared mailbox user] su on
        sm.sharedmailbox = su.sharedmailbox
    ) 
    inner join [Exchange Census] ec on su.useremail = ec.primarysmtpaddress
group by
    sm.sharedmailbox,
    sm.mailboxsmtpaddress
```